# Changing the footer settings so that at the beginning of each page, the footer number starts from the number 3

Tags: ms-word

How can I set the footer settings so that at the beginning of each page, the footer number starts with the number 3 (or any other number)?

In Footnote and Endnote dialog box I tried to change **start at** to 3, but **Numbering** automatically changes to **Continuous**.

Comment: See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm. This is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Comment: Footnotes and footers are very different parts of a Word document even though both appear at the bottom of a page. They are in different document "stories" in the Word object model. Page numbers are often in the footer part, never in the footnote part. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings

Answer (score 0):

In the Foonote and Endnote dialog box, under the "Numbering" section, you should see options like "Continuous", "Restart each section", "Restart each page", etc. Try selecting "Restart each section" and then set you "Start at" value.